# StatusStrip / StatusBar text not visible

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, statusbar, statusstrip

This is the first time I am using `StatusStrip` in Visual Studio 2017 using Visual C# Windows Forms. But a strange thing happened. The Status Bar is visible at the Bottom of the form but somehow it is not showing the text. In StatusStrip `Propetries` I set the `Text` property to **Ready**. Also in code I changed the StatusStrip Text Property twice ... But it doesnot show any text there.  :-(

Please guide me. Your response will be appreciated greatly. I shall be glad and thankful to you :-)

---

**Edit:** Thanks ! I have found the solution to this problem (guided by someone in comments). My mistake was that i didn't add `StatusLabel` to the top of `StatusStrip`. After making that change, now it works fine :-)

Comment: Did you also add a `StatusLabel` on top of the `StatusStrip`? There is an option below in dropdown form that lets you add 4 items in the `StatusStrip`. StatusLabel, ProgressBar, DrowDownButton, & SplitButton.

Comment: Ooops .. Thanks a Lot Sir :-) 
 I was not looking deeply into that ! But now I get it..
 Thanks @P.Pat ! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in my comment. All you need to do is add a `StatusLabel` which is one of the options you can add in your `StatusStrip` bar for any form of text to appear on it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @P.Pat .. I got your point :-) 
 Really learnt something new from you :-)

Comment: @HNLearner Glad to help. :)